# incompatible devices, how to make compatible?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, cordova

I am new to Android Development. I am currently working on a new app using Eclipse with the Apache Cordova extension. I successfully created and launched my app to Google Play. One BIG problem, my app is only compatible with certain devices. I made this app with "tablets" in mind, unfortunately none of them are compatible. In my android manifest, I have this:

supports-screens

```
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true"
```

But still no luck. I have tired endless Google searching and have come up empty handed with a solution. Any suggestions?

I also come across this:

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

    element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}

</script>
```

with information such as: device.name returns the name of the device's model or product. This value is set by the device manufacturer and may be different across versions of the same product, and, Get the device's model name.

var string = device.name;

But I am unsure of where to put these. Any suggestions?

I hope I have provided enough information for whoever is reading this to possibly provide a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the Android SDK version used to build the app and the `<uses-sdk>` and `<uses-permission>` part of the manifest? Please edit your question and post these.

Comment: Exactly can't get what's your problem but remember,
Different android devices takes their layouts from layout folders of your app. So, make sure you have placed layouts in  appropriate folder and also make sure you haven't use fixed size approach while designing.
also check your SDK versions added to manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Apache Cordova extension
But in android manifest we always mention two things

```
android:minSdkVersion
```

An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run

```
android:targetSdkVersion
```

An integer designating the API Level that the application is targetting.

So you may have to specify something like.

```
<uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8"           
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```